# how to save instance the activity without refreshing?

Tags: android

i switch to next screen  and then comes back to the original and wants to pick up where i  left off , save and restore data.In Activity 1:i have more than 10 buttons i can select and unselect button,if go to next screen and if i come back it should not reload,it should show me where i leftoff,

```
    up1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adultup1);
    up1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (upt1 == 0) {
                up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1);
                upt1 = 1;
            } else {
                up1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultup1_pressed);
                upt1 = 0;
            }
        }
    });  submit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TabFunctionality.setFirstTabFunctionality(TabFunctionality.FIRST_TAB, 1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdultTeeth.this, MainScreen.class);
            intent.putExtra("TEXT", view);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){}` and save all button states here and put it in the bundle. and while creating or resuming Activity get these values and restore your state..

Comment: how to store the button states?pls help me to do this?

Comment: You told to store button states right for example dwn16 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.adultdwn16);     dwn16.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  public void onClick(View view)      
if(dwnt16==0){dwn16.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultdwn16);  dwnt16=1;}else{      dwn16.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.adultdwn16_pressed);dwnt16=0;
}}}); how to store each button state

Comment: @user828948.. rea this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-stated

Comment: i understant that.but can i have some more detailed idea?

Comment: actually i want to store these in one class and i need to acess

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the whole picture of your activities as you just post a part of the code. I can tell you now is you could use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity(). StartActivity() and finish() will close Activity 1.

And you could get anything result of Activity 2 from onActivityResult() in Activity 1.